# Oracle regexp trailing spaces

Tags: regex, oracle

How do I remove only trailing spaces and chr(10) and chr(13) using Oracle regexp in a sql statement?

Example:

```
with txt as (select chr(10)||chr(10)||'  Hey Bob   '||chr(10)||chr(13) a  from dual)
select a
      ,regexp_replace(a,chr(10)||'+|'||chr(13)||'+|'||chr(32)||'+$','')
      ,regexp_replace(a,'['||chr(10)||'+'||chr(13)||'+'||chr(32)||'+]$','')
  from txt;
```

Desired result:

```
'  Hey Bob'
1. Leading and non-trailing spaces remain
2. Trailing spaces and eol characters removed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be better to use `[[:space:]]` to capture all whitespace:

```
regexp_replace(a, '[[:space:]]+$', '')
```

But if you explicitly want just the new-line (10), carriage-return (13) and space (32) characters, you can do:

```
regexp_replace(a, '[' || chr(10) || chr(13) || ' ]+$', '')
--                                              ^-- space character.
```

Comment: Thanks very much - this is what I needed - moving the '+' outside of the '[]'

Comment: I also tried using [:space:] instead of the explicit new-line, etc, and it works perfectly - handles tab characters as well.  Thanks!